# Pass value to void pointer in function parameter

Tags: c

i have small problem.

How can i cast value to void pointer:

```
void foo (void *arg){
    int test = *(int *)arg;
}

void main(){
    foo(&5);    <- ????
}
```

regards

Comment: What is `foo(&5);` supposed to be? Are you trying to pass the physical address 5?

Comment: Please take some time to learn about [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category). `5` is not an lvalue, and you cant get pointers to non-lvalues. You need to store the value in a variable, and pass a pointer to the variable.

Comment: You can't get address of a literal, use a variable instead.

Comment: Consider what should happen if the function stored a new value, like `*((int *)arg) = 42;` ... should it be discarded? Should the literal value `5` now be replaced with `42` everywhere else in the code? What should it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you really mean. Here's some options that may shed some light for you:

```
void foo (void *arg){
    int test = *(int *)arg;
}

void main(){
    int val = 5

    // Pass the variable address in
    foo(&val);

    // See what's add memory address 0x5
    foo((void*)5);

    fooPtr(&val); // val is incremented
    fooByValue(val); // val is unchanged
}

void fooIntPtr(int *ptr){
    (*ptr)++;
}

void fooByValue(int test){
    // same effect as your "foo" but safe and quicker
    test++;
}
```

(For anyone learning C++ you could also do pass by reference: `void fooRef(int &val)`)

Comment: C doesn't have references.

Comment: And `fooByValue` doesn't modify the passed-in value.

Comment: Thanks for the C++ catch! 

`fooByValue` is not trying to modify the outside value - please see the comment when called. I put that in because the code in the question does the same thing: it immediately makes a copy of the int the same as passing by value :)